# How do I stop an auto fit table from overflowing the right page margin?

Tags: rtf

I have an RTF table with fixed widths, I would like it to become responsive when the page orientation or paper size is modified. I seem to be partially there using \clftsWidth2\clwWidth2500 (50% width) but, the table appears to be getting the width from the page rather than the margins  and is flowing over the edge.

```
\trowd\trautofit1\trrh320\clvertalc\b0\trkeep\trgaph75\trleft8\trbrdrl\brdrs\brdrw15\brdrcf2 \trbrdrt\brdrs\brdrw15\brdrcf2 \trbrdrr\brdrs\brdrw15\brdrcf2 \trbrdrb\brdrs\brdrw15\brdrcf2 \trpaddl75\trpaddr75\trpaddfl3\trpaddfr3
\clbrdrl\brdrw15\brdrs\brdrcf2\clbrdrt\clvertalc\clftsWidth2\clwWidth2500\cellx4509
\clbrdrl\brdrw15\brdrs\brdrcf2\clbrdrt\clvertalc\clftsWidth2\clwWidth2500\cellx9018
```

I would like the table to sit within the page margins